# PostgreSQL JDBC driver with data encryption

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, encryption, jdbc

Do you know whether PostgreSQL JDBC driver with on-the-fly data encryption exists?

I use PostgreSQL database on Heroku and have requirement to encrypt some sensitive client data on database level. How it's possible to implement this?

Heroku allows to use PostgreSQL `pgcrypto` module but it allows only per-column encryption and work with the module looks cumbersome. So I'm thinking about data encryption on Java side.

Comment: Maybe little bit help : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157422/store-encrypted-user-data-in-database

Comment: The driver is pretty much irrelevant here. It only supports encrypted transmission over the network (using SSL). Everything else needs to be done by your application.

Comment: Your Question is not clear, please revise. Are you asking about encrypting the data *stored* in the database, "data at rest"? Or are you asking about encrypting data in transit *to* the database, going over the network, "data in motion"?

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm asking about "data at rest"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why irrelevant? JDBC driver is a gate from app to DB. So I'm asking about JDBC encrypted proxy over PostgreSQL JDBC driver. If it's exist obviously.

Comment: As I wrote: the only encryption that the **driver** supports is encrypting the data that is sent over the network. The server will decrypt that and store the data un-encrypted. If you want something different you have to implement it yourself. If you want to encrypt the data that's stored on the server, use an encrypted filesystem

Comment: If you want to encrypt data within your Java code (before it hits the database) be aware that if the database itself cannot read the data anymore, querying and indexing the tables will be very difficult.

Comment: Heroku PG is [encrypted at rest](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-production-tier-technical-characterization#data-encryption) (i.e. filesystem is encrypted). If you want individual fields to be encrypted (for instance a credit card number) you would need to encrypt that data prior to sending it to the DB. You could use a [NaCl Symmetric SecretBox for that](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox#combined-mode). Several NaCl bindings are available for Java. JDBC won't automate that for you but an ORM field type might be possible

Answer (score -2):

## JDBC driver irrelevant to encrypted storage

For encrypting data “at rest”, that is, when written to storage, the JDBC driver is irrelevant.

A JDBC driver’s job is to mediate *between* a Java app with Java types and a database with database types. The driver communicates with the database, relying your queries, and then marshaling back the results. The driver converts data between the types used on either side.

The JDBC driver does *not* affect how the data is stored by the database.